# color classification algorithm for python

Tags: python, classification

I am in need of an algorithm that classifies the colors. I have scraped colors from images and of course, the result is 6000 different colors, which is useless for any statistical analysis.

Below is a try but the code grew up so fast and messy that my mind exploded and I just can't handle it anymore and still, there are many colors that do not look at all like blue,red,green,yellow,cyan,magenta .

any ideas?

```
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
from genericpath import samefile
from pickle import TRUE
from PIL import ImageColor
from yachalk import chalk
import os

with open('colors.txt', 'r') as f:
    colors = f.readlines()


global chosen_color
# chosen_color = "#fff200"
chosen_color = ""

def get_rgb(color):
    global red 
    red = 0
    red = ImageColor.getcolor(color, "RGB")[0]
    global green 
    green = 0
    green = ImageColor.getcolor(color, "RGB")[1]
    global blue 
    blue = 0
    blue = ImageColor.getcolor(color, "RGB")[2]

    print(red, green, blue)

    global same
    if ((abs(abs(red) - abs(green))) <=20) and ((abs(abs(red) - abs(blue))) <=20) and ((abs(abs(green) - abs(blue))) <=20):
        same = 1
    else:
        same = 0

    if ((red >= 30) and (green >= 30) and (blue >= 30)) and ((red <= 220) and (green <= 220) and (blue <= 220)) and (same == 1):
        # print("grey")
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("grey"))
    elif ((red < 30) and (green < 30) and (blue < 30)) and (same == 1):
        # print("black")
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("black"))
    elif ((red > 220) and (green > 220) and (blue > 220)) and (same == 1):
        # print("white")
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("white"))
    elif ((red >= 30) or (green >= 30) or (blue >= 30)) and ((red <= 220) or (green <= 220) or (blue <= 220)) and (red > green) and (red > blue) and (not(abs(abs(red) - abs(green))) <=50):
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("red"))
    elif ((red >= 30) or (green >= 30) or (blue >= 30)) and ((red <= 220) or (green <= 220) or (blue <= 220)) and (green > red) and (green > blue) and (not(abs(abs(blue) - abs(green))) <=50):
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("green"))
    elif ((red >= 30) or (green >= 30) or (blue >= 30)) and ((red <= 220) or (green <= 220) or (blue <= 220)) and (blue > red) and (blue > green) and (not(abs(abs(blue) - abs(red))) <=50) and (not(abs(abs(blue) - abs(green))) <=50):
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("blue"))
    elif ((red >= 30) or (green >= 30) or (blue >= 30)) and ((red <= 220) or (green <= 220) or (blue <= 220)) and ((abs(abs(red) - abs(green))) <=50) and ((red > blue) or (green > blue)) and abs(abs(blue) - abs(red) >=50) and abs(abs(blue) - abs(green) >=50):
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("yellow"))
    elif ((red >= 30) or (green >= 30) or (blue >= 30)) and ((red <= 220) or (green <= 220) or (blue <= 220)) and ((abs(abs(blue) - abs(green))) <=50) and ((blue > red) or (green > red)):
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("cyan"))
    elif ((red >= 30) or (green >= 30) or (blue >= 30)) and ((red <= 220) or (green <= 220) or (blue <= 220)) and ((abs(abs(blue) - abs(red))) <=50) and ((blue > green) or (red > green)):
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("magenta"))
    else:
        print("not grey")
        print(chalk.bg_hex(chosen_color).black("other"))



for color in colors:
    chosen_color = "#"+color.split('\n')[0]
    try:
        get_rgb(chosen_color)
    except:
        # print('wrong color code')
        continue
```

Comment: To me, I think rather than trying to both design and implement simultaneously, which is difficult, I instead suggest coming up with a concrete plan, or a flowchart, or some complete description, not written in code, which fully describes how you want the logic to work. That will force you to think about all the possibilities and come up with a solid plan that you can just implement straightforwardly. Then you can test it, and if there are issues, assuming you implemented the plan correctly, then you could know for sure that those issues lie in the design, which would need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

https://webcolors.readthedocs.io/en/1.11.1/

so simple. That was the only thing I neded.